# having trouble with ports and deploying react/node project to digital ocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, digital-ocean

I tried to deploy my project to Digital Ocean.

At one point I was able to see my react client when I went to my_ip:8080 which was the port it was running on for whatever reason.

I set up SSL and then `cd etc/nginx/sites-enabled` hit vim default and started to edit. Here is where I started to run into problems, where my react project stopped showing up, and where ultimately I'm stuck.

so this is what is in that file right now

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    listen 80;
    server_name my_website.com;
    rewrite ^/a(.*) https://my_website.com/$1 permanent;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}


    root /var/www/client/build;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name my_website.com;
    ssl_certificate /root/my_website.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/my_website.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {

    }
```

something is clearly not working here though.

if I do `pm2 list` it will show me `index` running on 0 with `status: online` and `static-page-server-8080` running on 1, but with a `status: errored`.

I tried to set up ufw and I'm not even sure if that messed anything up or not.

So at the moment if I go to my IP in the browser I get nothing. if I add a port at the end I get nothing. how should I go about fixing this? Should I just scrap it and try over?

Answer (score 1):

Take a read through the documentation [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04). And for SSL, [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) is useful.

I'd also suggest, as a sanity check:

1. Stop everything running you see in `pm2 list`.
2. Start your project running directly in the terminal on port 8080 and try and visit it from the browser.
3. This will tell you if it's a problem with your code, pm2, or how you're setting up nginx.

Also, this is what my config looks like below. You're localhost probably shouldn't be commented out.

> server {
>       server_name www.foo.com foo.com;
>
> ```
> location / {
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
>     proxy_http_version 1.1;
>     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
>     proxy_set_header Host $host;
>     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>  }
>
>
> listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
> ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
> ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
> include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
> ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
> ```
>
> }

Comment: ok I've gotten my client to show on my root url. my question is now where exactly do I set my server to run?

this may be some fundamental misunderstanding on my part, but I'm curious as to where exactly do I mount the server and how do I access it from my front-end client?